# Mysql select Month names as numeric

Tags: mysql

I need to get Month number from `event` table using a mysql select query. here my EVENT table,

[image]

query
`SELECT month(str_to_date(month,'%d')) AS m FROM`event``

but the result was 
[image]

how can I convert my month column as numeric..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %M insted of %d

```
mysql> SELECT month(str_to_date('April','%M')) AS m;
+------+
| m    |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```